# Group by week of the year in Tableau

Tags: date, tableau-api, dayofweek

I have a table where I only have week number and year (and another not timing variables).

- Week number : I have it as 1, 2,3,4,5 up to 53.
- Year : 2020, 2021, etc

Therefore for ever week-year I have a row.

**Goal**:
I have seen that in Tableau you can show by week too but showing the first day of the week (see screenshot).

[image]

How to create/convert a column/existing columns so that first day of week is shown as date instead.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. Try this formula:

```
DATETRUNC('week',DATEPARSE("w-yyyy",STR([Week])+"-"+ STR([Year])))
```

DATEPARSE converts your week and year to a date.

DATETRUNC returns the first date of each week.